# Появление блока, если поле input не пусто

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

[Линк на сайт](http://testbcard.dtraduga.vh55.hosterby.com)

Разрешение 767 и ниже. В хедере появляется поиск с крестиком для очистки: 
[Скрин](http://joxi.ru/KAgGpvvT4pXdRA)

Крестик изначально отключаю (diaplay:none)
И хочу его включить, когда в поле input поиска начинаю что-то писать.

```
<div class="mobile_search_header_menu">
   <input id="textInput" type="text" value="">   
   <button id="clearButton">х</button> 
</div>

var clearButton = document.getElementById("clearButton"),
    textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");

clearButton.onclick = function(e){ 
textInput.value = "";
}

(очистка по кнопке работает если ее включить)

(появление самой кнопки "х" не срабатывает)
if (textInput.value != ""){ 
   clearButton.style.display = "block";
}
```

Ошибок в консоли нет, но и появление блока не срабатывает.

Comment: На какое событие вы привязываете проверку != "", если не секрет? Повесьте на onkeydown+onkeyup и все станет нормально

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен данным образом: [линк на генератор](http://jsfiddle.net/SVxbW/)

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
       if ($(this).val()) {
          $("button").show();
       }
       else {
          $("button").hide();
       }
    });
    $("button").click(function () {
       $("input").val('');
       $(this).hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Привяжите проверку наличия текста в поле к событию клавиш

Пример на jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $("#text").keydown(CheckInput).keyup(CheckInput);
});

function CheckInput() {
  if ($("#text").val() == "") {
    $("#close").css({
      "display": "none"
    });
  } else {
    $("#close").css({
      "display": "block"
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" type="text">
<div id="close" style="display:none">[CLOSE]</div>
```

UPD: Пример на JavaScript

```js
function CheckInput(e) {
  if (e.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("clearButton").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("clearButton").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" onkeydown="CheckInput(this)" onkeyup="CheckInput(this)">
<div id="clearButton" style="display:none">[CLOSE]</div>
```

Comment: Я и писал на JS, а как вы ответили, теперь в затупе как JS и jQuery скрестить. Если можно можете на основе моего показать?

Comment: Вам нужно проверять текст в input не один раз при старте страницы, а каждый раз, когда в поле вводятся буквы - то есть нажимаются клавиши. Это событие keydown (клавиша нажата). Однако есть тонкость - при срабатывании keydown в поле input содержимое еще старое, а при срабатывании keyup - уже новое. Также есть тонкости зажатия клавиш, они генерируют серии событий. Чтобы не вникать во весь этот зоопарк, вешаем обработчик на оба события. Обновил код

Comment: Это пока для меня еще слишком сложно будет. А если простой вариант. При клике в input нужный блок отображается, как только ушли из него он снова пропадает.
Или это с focus нужно использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так на js будет?:

```
  if (textInput.val == "") {
      clearButton.style.display = "none"; 
        else 
       {
        clearButton.style.display = "block"
  }
}
```